# ¿Como conectar mi base de datos de dolibarr en un archivo php?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

trate de conectar mi base de datos sacando mis datos desde cpanel , pero no me conecta.
`$conexion =mysqli_connect("localhost","usuario","pass","bd");` 
intente mediante esta forma la conexion y no me funciono.
atento a sus comentarios.

Comment: Decir que no funciono no alcanza, ¿aparece algún error?, seguro que esas son tus credenciales? es decir tu contraseña es `pass`?

Comment: Sería conveniente comprobar tu conexión en caso que fallezca, gusta debajo de la línea `$conexion` podrías añadir esta línea `if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error()); exit(); }`

Comment: lo unico que me aparece es este error

Comment: Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'ahoravoy_afclerp'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\dolibarr\www\dolibarr\htdocs\Ficha\conexion.php on line 2